# How to use onClick function to make a button show a text view

Tags: android, button, textview

I'm really sorry because I'm writing this after a lot of similar questions that (I guess you know) already exist, but I need your help. I tried different methods as described in other posts, but none work for me. I'm new to Android development and I've have a simple "Hello World!" app. I customized it with a custom material design theme and a button, also customized. I was trying to use the "onClick" function to show a TextView when the button is clicked, but I don't know how to do it. Here is my Relative Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/helloworld1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/press_here"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:background="@color/Red"
        android:translationY="40dp"/>
```

And here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.giuskiller.material;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I was trying to use "onClick" function "*... where is that function in your code?

Comment: I've deleted it because it doesn't worked

Comment: You still should include it so others can show you where you went wrong. Otherwise, we have no idea.

Comment: Understood, sorry. Next time I'll write everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a *method* that will show the `TextView`, then assign that method to the `onClick` *attribute* of your `Button`, like so:

Layout XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/helloworld1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/press_here"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:onClick="showTextView"
        android:background="@color/Red"
        android:translationY="40dp"/>
```

Activity:

```
package com.giuskiller.material;

import android.app.; import android.os.;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override 
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
  public void showTextView(View view){
    findViewById(R.id.helloworld1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally not the best on SO.

Comment: Thank you very much, as already said, I'm really sorry bout this duplicate question. Everyone has different java code so I didn't figured out how to implement it in mine. P.S. I've noticed a lot of grammatical correction...i'm Italian, i make mistakes...apologize